# How to place two text-fields as one viewport in java?

Tags: java, user-interface, jtextfield, jcomponent

How could I set 2 textfields as one viewport and set each textfield to expand as more text is typed in, rather than adding a scroll bar to each textfield.

I find it hard to describe it with words so I have uploaded a sketch.

[image]

Comment: :D thanks and my apologies for such a sketch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this, everytime you type something in, it gets bigger:

```
field.addKeyListener(this);
```

And in your `KeyListener` implementation this:

```
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
    field.setSize(field.getWidth() + 10, field.getHeight());
    repaint();
}
```

Comment: In this case I would also have to calculate and reposition the texfield below. But still an option, thanks.